# delete row in cascade postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Sorry about images, but I don't know how to make a similar example.
I have db on postgresql with tables:
[image]

Foreign keys for interest:  `engine_labeledimage.job_id` <-> `engine_job.id` and `engine_labeledimageattributeval.image_id` <-> `engine_labeledimage.id`

So I want delete any row in `engine_labeledimage` and `engine_labeledimageattributeval` that connect to specific `id` in `engine_job`. Here sample my code:

```
delete from engine_labeledimageattributeval 
using engine_labeledimage 
where engine_labeledimage.job_id in (3981,3983,3984);

delete from engine_labeledimage
using engine_job
where engine_job.id in ( 3981,3983,3984);
```

Its work, but code **delete any rows in tables** (((((

What I do wrong (except back-up data and delete policies) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the reference condition in first query:

```
delete from engine_labeledimageattributeval 
using engine_labeledimage 
where engine_labeledimageattributeval.image_id = engine_labeledimage.id
and engine_labeledimage.job_id in (3981,3983,3984);
```

Comment: Ok, I got, I also need add same reference  in second query

Comment: @TeoK yes, but you could also write: `delete from engine_labeledimage where job_id  in ( 3981,3983,3984)`.